# Cross-Platform encryption failing in different Android versions

Tags: java, c#, android, encryption, pkcs#5

I have found a nice little bit of code [here](https://zenu.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/aes-128bit-cross-platform-java-and-c-encryption-compatibility/) that implements a cross-platform encryption. In this case C# and Java.

I have implemented this in `Android version 4.4.2 (AVD)` and it works like a charm. However, I have since moved to `Android 5.0.1 (Samsung)` and it fails to decrypt what the other platform has encrypted. On both sides, Java and C# produce a *Padding Error*.

What has changed in android versions that would cause this error?

The code that is being used is below:

**JAVA CODE:**

```
private final String characterEncoding = "UTF-8";
private final String cipherTransformation = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
private final String aesEncryptionAlgorithm = "AES";

public  byte[] decrypt(byte[] cipherText, byte[] key, byte [] initialVector) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException{

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherTransformation);
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpecy = new SecretKeySpec(key, aesEncryptionAlgorithm);
    IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(initialVector);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpecy, ivParameterSpec);
    cipherText = cipher.doFinal(cipherText);
    return cipherText;
}

public byte[] encrypt(byte[] plainText, byte[] key, byte [] initialVector) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException{
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherTransformation);
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, aesEncryptionAlgorithm);
    IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(initialVector);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
    plainText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);
    return plainText;
}

private byte[] getKeyBytes(String key) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    byte[] keyBytes= new byte[16];
    byte[] parameterKeyBytes= key.getBytes(characterEncoding);
    System.arraycopy(parameterKeyBytes, 0, keyBytes, 0, Math.min(parameterKeyBytes.length, keyBytes.length));
    return keyBytes;
}

/// <summary>
/// Encrypts plaintext using AES 128bit key and a Chain Block Cipher and returns a base64 encoded string
/// </summary>
/// <param name="plainText">Plain text to encrypt</param>
/// <param name="key">Secret key</param>
/// <returns>Base64 encoded string</returns>
public String encrypt(String plainText, String key) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException{
    byte[] plainTextbytes = plainText.getBytes(characterEncoding);
    byte[] keyBytes = getKeyBytes(key);
    return Base64.encodeToString(encrypt(plainTextbytes,keyBytes, keyBytes), Base64.DEFAULT);
}

/// <summary>
/// Decrypts a base64 encoded string using the given key (AES 128bit key and a Chain Block Cipher)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="encryptedText">Base64 Encoded String</param>
/// <param name="key">Secret Key</param>
/// <returns>Decrypted String</returns>
public String decrypt(String encryptedText, String key) throws KeyException, GeneralSecurityException, GeneralSecurityException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, IOException{
    byte[] cipheredBytes = Base64.decode(encryptedText, Base64.DEFAULT);
    byte[] keyBytes = getKeyBytes(key);
    return new String(decrypt(cipheredBytes, keyBytes, keyBytes), characterEncoding);
}
```

**C# Code:**

```
public RijndaelManaged GetRijndaelManaged(String secretKey)
{
    var keyBytes = new byte[16];
    var secretKeyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey);
    Array.Copy(secretKeyBytes, keyBytes, Math.Min(keyBytes.Length, secretKeyBytes.Length));
    return new RijndaelManaged{
        Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
        Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
        KeySize = 128,
        BlockSize = 128,
        Key = keyBytes,
        IV = keyBytes
    };
}

public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] plainBytes, RijndaelManaged rijndaelManaged){
    return rijndaelManaged.CreateEncryptor()
        .TransformFinalBlock(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
}

public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] encryptedData, RijndaelManaged rijndaelManaged){
    return rijndaelManaged.CreateDecryptor()
        .TransformFinalBlock(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);
}

/// <summary>
/// Encrypts plaintext using AES 128bit key and a Chain Block Cipher and returns a base64 encoded string
/// </summary>
/// <param name="plainText">Plain text to encrypt</param>
/// <param name="key">Secret key</param>
/// <returns>Base64 encoded string</returns>
public String Encrypt(String plainText, String key){
    var plainBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(Encrypt(plainBytes, GetRijndaelManaged(key)));
}

/// <summary>
/// Decrypts a base64 encoded string using the given key (AES 128bit key and a Chain Block Cipher)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="encryptedText">Base64 Encoded String</param>
/// <param name="key">Secret Key</param>
/// <returns>Decrypted String</returns>
public String Decrypt(String encryptedText, String key){
    var encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Decrypt(encryptedBytes, GetRijndaelManaged(key)));
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the outcome in hex if you encrypt "hello world" on both systems? do both system have the same character encoding (i.e. utf8 without BOM) and the same line encoding (i.e. cr+lf)? are there additional blanks? Where is the code that adds the paddings?

Comment: When you say "Systems" do you mean the different versions of android? as thats where the problem seems to be.

Comment: These are only retoric questions to give you possible causes of the problem.  You should also check if android 5.0.1 can decrypt it-s own encryption.

Comment: I will of course be checking everything like that thanks. Also it does decrypt its own encryption.